# Acessar a varialvel após requisição ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou tentar atribuir um valor a uma variável após a resposta de uma requisição, porém minha variável sempre retorna *null*;

```
 function validaItensReceita() {

 var validRecVec;
 var ajaxValid = $('.urlCheckReceitaVeiculo').data('url');
 var placa = $('#veiculo-placa').val();
 var inscricaoMunicipal = $('#contribuintereceita-  inscricao_municipal').val();

 if (inscricaoMunicipal) {
  $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: ajaxValid + '?inscricao=' + inscricaoMunicipal,
  }).then(function (response) {
      var res = JSON.parse(response);
      if (res.status == 406) {
          validRecVec = false;
      }else{
         validRecVec = true;
       }
  });

}
 return validRecVec;
}
```

Preciso obter um bool dessa variável *validRecVec*

Comment: Alguém me corrija se eu estiver equivocado, mas essa chamada `then()`, em formato de `Promise`, para [`JQuery.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) não existe.

Comment: sim @AugustoVasques, seria o `done` no lugar do `then`, segundo a documentação: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
*"porém minha variável sempre retorna null"* se está retornando a variável fora do tratamento do promise vai retornar null mesmo, esse `return validRecVec;` é executado antes de obter o retorno do ajax